# Why I don't get the same result?

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm running same code in different server but i don't get the same result.
[https://imgur.com/a/xUAhvNY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FigX2.png)

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+20 year"));
echo "<br>PHP version: ".phpversion();
?>
```

Comment: When I write strtotime("+15 year") the result is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to timezone but to a [limitation of the UNIX timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) on systems on which the timestamp is stored as a 32bit number. The server on the left is probably being affected by the problem.

Note from the [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) page:

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)
>
> [...]
>
> For 64-bit versions of PHP, the valid range of a timestamp is effectively infinite, as 64 bits can represent approximately 293 billion years in either direction.

Answer (score -1):

Add at the beginning of your script;

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
```